# Firestore Rules for content owner access

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

So I am having an issue with firestore rules when attempting to set the rules so only the person who created the document within the collection can read and write to it. I keep getting permission denied when attempting to set them. These are the rules I have currently:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   
    match /users/{uid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    
    match /accounts/{document} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId
    }
  }
}
```

I have two collections, as seen above. I have tried numerous variations of these rules in order to allow the person who made the document in the accounts collection to see it, while no other users can, yet I always get permission denied. I do have a field inside the document that grabs the userId, and the username, but not sure what the actual issue is. If it's something in the flutter code that's causing it, this is how I have the StreamBuilder set up:

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('accounts')
            .orderBy('siteName')
            .snapshots(),
```

**EDIT:**
I found that making it a subcollection and using these rules worked!

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /users/{uid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
   
    match /users/{uid}/accounts/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    
  }
}
```

If there is a better practice, or if someone can guide me on what was the issue originally still, I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase [security rules do not filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters). Instead they merely ensure that your code doesn't try to read any data it is not authorized for.

Knowing that, we can see that this code doesn't meet the requirements of your rules:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('accounts')
        .orderBy('siteName')
        .snapshots(),
```

To meet the requirement of your rules, the code must only request documents for the current user. So something like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('accounts')
        .orderBy('siteName')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
        .snapshots(),
```